# How to get PrivateKey from AWS CloudHSM via JCE provider

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudhsm

I am new in AWS CloudHSM and document signing.
I want to sign a document via AWS CloudHSM using the JCE provider. I have found [an example][1] how to do it. The `sign` method in this example looks like the following:

```
public static byte[] sign(byte[] message, PrivateKey key, String signingAlgorithm)
            throws SignatureException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance(signingAlgorithm, "CloudHSM");
        sig.initSign(key);
        sig.update(message);
        return sig.sign();
    }
```

As you can see, I need to pass `PrivateKey` parameter for signing the document, but I can't understand how I can get the `PrivateKey wrapper` from the CloudHSM.
I have the next incoming data:

1. a byte array that I should sign;
2. an alias of a key that is kept in the CloudHSM.

I try to extract the PrivateKey in the next way:

```
public PrivateKey getKey(String keyAlias) {
    try {
            if (Security.getProvider(CloudHsmProvider.PROVIDER_NAME) == null) {
                Security.addProvider(new CloudHsmProvider());
            }
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(CloudHsmProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            Key key = keyStore.getKey("test", null); // But I get only a CloudHsmRsaPublicKey
        } catch (IOException e) {
            
        }
}
```

and I get a `CloudHsmRsaPublicKey`, and I can't understand how can I get a `PrivateKey wrapper` by key allies via JCE provider.
Can anyone help me?
[1]: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cloudhsm-jce-examples/blob/c57ad1bd140598440b945b1057973f84868bd6e8/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/cloudhsm/examples/RSAOperationsRunner.java#L109